# My app is lagging on iPhone when I install it with XCode, but not if I install with TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, testflight

And it is uselessly slow. The app is exactly the same; it is just installed with TestFlight instead of XCode. My only guess is, that when it is installed with XCode, it runs additional processes that aids testing the app, but I doubt that is why.

I run the app on a iPhone 7, and it is a rather light app. It does not have any heavy graphics, computing or networking.

Comment: That's probably why.  Make a release build and see if that matches TestFlight

Comment: What do you mean by "install with Xcode"? Do you run a debug build from Xcode or do you create a release build, package it as .ipa and then install via Xcode? Debug builds always run slower than release builds, because they are not optimised by the compiler.

Comment: If it's a Photos extension, it sets up quite a bit of debugging processes no matter what. But - if you stop running it from Xcode (and the extension also stops) and then you run it from the device, all is well. Since apps can behave like that too (you start/stop from Xcode), try running your app **after** Xcode "installs" it.

Comment: I just ran a Release Build and now there's no problems. Thanks!